# How to uppercase the word "CHAPTER 1" in chapter title?

Tags: chapters, titles, titlesec, uppercase

I am using below **code** to make the chapter titles uppercased,

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\large \bfseries \centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\MakeUppercase}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{-10pt}{-20pt}{25pt}

\chapter{Introduction}

Hello

\end{document}
```

**Output** is like,

[image]

But I want to the word `Chapter 1` as uppercased as well. Also, I want to reflect the uppercase format in the table of content too.

**How can I do so?**

Comment: You need to provide a small complete working example that shows the problem.  We don't even know what `\documentclass` you are using.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes thanks for suggestion. I have updated as MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do it for both `\chaptertitlename` and the  chapter title:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{titlesec, titletoc}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\large \bfseries \centering}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\large\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{-10pt}{-20pt}{25pt}

\titlecontents{chapter}[6em]{\bigskip\bfseries}%\vspace{1cm}%
{\contentslabel[\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}~\thecontentslabel]{7em}\MakeUppercase}%
{\MakeUppercase}%numberless chapters%
{\hfill\contentspage}[\medskip]%

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter {Introduction}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That actually solved my problem 1. However did not solve the second part `I want to reflect the uppercase format in the table of content too`.

Comment: Do you want in toc only the chapter titles , or also the word ‘CHAPTER’?

Comment: I want both. It would be better if I get both options available. @Bernard

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan: I've updated my answer with the `titlecode` necessary for that. Is it what you want?

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

As you were told in the comments, you shoould provide a MNW. But, in principle, you could get what you want adding

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{\MakeUppercase{Chapter}}
\makeatother
```

to the preamble of your document.

Comment: Or even simpler `\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{CHAPTER}`

Comment: Thanks. That actually solved my problem 1. However did not solve the second part `I want to reflect the uppercase format in the table of content too`.